# Backing up Windows over SSH

Tags: windows, ssh, backup

I was wondering if people have any suggestions for backing up a Windows machine over SSH. I know of tools like Delta Copy, but that doesn't work well, because it doesn't know about junctions on NTFS, resulting in infinite loops in directories in Windows 7.

I also know there are ways to do Rdiff-backup or Rsync, but I was looking for something a little more simple (and something aware of junctions).

I also know about WinSCP, but I'm looking for something a little more complicated (and again, aware of junctions) :)

So, I'm looking for a next-next-finish style of incremental backup over SSH for windows with junction support :)

The way Microsoft SyncToy works is nice, but it doesn't support an SSH target...

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there are ready made stuff out there to sync over ssh from windows. Few months back I had to do the same thing, but I finally ended up writing a unison + plink script to get it working. There is also a front end to unison called winison. Some of the links that may help you

http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/UnisonKeySetup
http://code.google.com/p/winison/

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to find any GnuTool method that can handle anything other than simple file-backup for Windows. And even those have trouble with locked and open files, since their home operating system (Posix-based *nix) still allows read access to all files.

This is a problem since restoring a Windows machine from backup requires more than just "restore all the files, redo the boot environment, reboot".

Personally, I find rsync to be too simple for Windows, so am automatically leery of something even more simple than that. However, if all you're looking for is file-backup from Windows, Rsync will definitely get the job done (within it's limitations).

Another method I've seen used successfully is to reverse the direction of the backup. The backup-server mounts the Windows share you want backed up, and then does whatever local-file based backup methods via that (again, rsync works well for this).

Comment: The locks are an additional problem I forgot about already... Are there any commercial tools then? They use Windows, so they should be used to closed-source non-free (in both senses of the word) software. If it's necessary, I could setup WebDAV, but I'd rather not.

Comment: @Halfgaar One option I've heard of, but runs completely counter to your desire for simplicity, is [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/). Open source and even does Shadow Copy, which will handle the locking/open problem. But like all big backup products, requires an *environment*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're backing up the whole system, you might want to consider clonezilla. This would of course require that boot into the clonezilla environment and backup the whole disk to a ssh location.